# How to remove LUKS auto-unlock?

Tags: linux, gnome, luks, gnome-keyring, cryptsetup

Unfortunately my drive **unlocks automatically**. This makes the whole encryption useless. How do I turn off this annoying *feature* on a specified drive (e.g. `/dev/x`) ?

The `cryptsetup` command I've found is **not documented**. I'm afraid this could erase the whole drive!

```
cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/x
```

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering how on earth can a drive get locked while it is mounted - it is bound for a disaster. Anyway, GNOME Disks (which is a front end to udisk) should have some sort of settings available for tweaking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LUKS doesn't “auto-unlock” a volume. The volume becomes accessible when you open it, which requires the key. The volume remains inaccessible when you close it; you can only close it when it is not in use, so you must close any open file and unmount the filesystem.

`cryptsetup luksRemoveKey` would remove the key from the volume, which would make it unreadable. Don't do this. The unlocking isn't happening because of LUKS, but because a program is calling `cryptsetup luksOpen`. You need to avoid storing your key in that program.

It looks like you have a keyring application that has recorded the key for the volume, specifically [gnome-keyring](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring). Remove the key from the keyring. You can manipulate your keyring with [Seahorse](https://live.gnome.org/Seahorse).